# Copying a project in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, copy

Is there an **easy** way to copy a project in **Visual Studio 2010**?

Copying a folder with project to a different path and opening it results in the following error.

[image: Error]

I'm interested only in solutions that **would not involve** more than **1 simple action**. I'm creating a simple console project that I'm going to be copying hudreds of times, and not really a fan of going into settings and repeating multiple steps every time such a simple things needs to be done.

I'm using **Visual C++ Express 2010**. Note the project structure below. I created it as an *Empty Project* and added 1 single file *main.cpp* to it.

[image: Project structure]

The project was created using the [**settings**](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/33457177/Screenshots/New%20Project_2011-12-04_22-02-23.png).

The project in explorer looks like [**this**](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/33457177/Screenshots/void_template_2011-12-04_22-15-51.png).

There is a **Copy Project** function, but this means more than 1 manual action:

- openning the old project;
- pressing Copy on the menu;
- closing the old Project;

Copying a parent folder of a solution would work, but that creates an unnecessary folder that I'd have to navigate in each copied project every time I need to access the copied project. I would like to avoid any unnecessary "pass-through" folders.

Note that create directory for solution was unchecked when the project was created, see the link above. If this was checked it would result in 2 unnecessary pass-through folders. There is a **solution folder**, **folder where solution is created** and a **project folder**. By unchecking the checkbox you get rid of project folder and project files are created in the solution directory, that still leaves the other 2 - I would like to have one for the reasons above.

Comment: Did you "hardcode" any of the paths in your project? If you use relative paths and the variables for project/solution paths, there should be no problem. And curious> "I'm creating a simple console project that I'm going to be copying hudreds of times" Why?

Comment: is main.cpp in the same folder or in subfolder to the path of .sln?

Comment: If you're making the same sort of project many times, perhaps consider creating it as a project template (C#) or wizard (C++) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96xz4cw2.aspx

Comment: I did hardcode the project path when creating a **new project** (see the link in the updated question). Is there any way of avoiding that hardcoded path?

Comment: Template is not the best solution for me, as creating a project from a template is more complex (open visual studio, navigate through menus to create a project from a template) than copying a folder. I think I'm going to try that next, but would rather stick to copying a folder.

Comment: Yes, main.cpp and .sln are in the same folder. Please see the full folder structure in the image link attached to the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would be nice if you could just copy the vcxproj file itself -- but you cannot. The problem is that project files contain a GUID that Globally Uniquely IDentifies that project within Visual Studio; internally, projects are usually referenced by their GUID, not by their name. When you copy a project file, you are copying the GUID without changing it, which won't work. Note that both the vcxproj file and any sln files will reference the GUID, so you might want to avoid adding it to any sln files until after the GUID is changed.

The GUID section of the project file looks like this:

```
<ProjectGuid>{830DD595-EAD5-475B-9360-E4C2FD7CCC53}</ProjectGuid>
```

This line occurs precisely once in a valid vcxproj file. Any solution outside of the IDE for copying projects is going to have to change the GUID manually. The only way you're going to get this down to a single step is to write yourself a tool that changes the GUID -- although a search-and-replace with a good editor might be fast enough. You may find the function `UuidCreate()` helpful. Note that direct editing of the vcxproj file is also helpful if you need to change absolute paths to relative ones, etc.

Or, of course, you could just keep manually copying them using the tool within Visual Studio; the reason it exists is probably as a way to automate the GUID changeovers you need to do. I'll note that for our own projects, I frequently use Notepad for editing project files, though Notepad++ or UltraEdit are an even better idea.

Comment: Thank you! So copying a project in VS 2010 can't be done in a simple action, without writing a special script to change GUID, or using VS Copy Tool.

Comment: This information is incorrect. Visual Studio will automatically change the GUID of a project when you add it to a visual studio solution if it already has a different project with the same GUID. So you can copy the project folder without any problem in an explorer.

Comment: BertR: I have personally had problems with Visual Studio not doing this, causing nasty bugs when editing configuration settings (this would have been either VS2003 or VS2005, not sure). I haven't tried this in a later version, so you're likely right, at least for newer VS versions. At any rate, it's good to be aware of the GUID issues, since as of VS2010, the solution file still uses GUIDs to reference the project files, so any fully automated solution will have to deal with this.

Answer (score 4):

It would seem you have some strange requirements that aren't usually there, such as no extra folders, copying with only **1** simple action etc.

I would suggest writing a simple application / script to do this for you, then you can just click 'run' on that app.

The app could

Always copy from a particular 'template' folder.
Automatically navigate explorer to the new solution or even better, open the new solution for you?

If you need help, reply back.

Comment: This is how we do it.  VS solutions and projects are getting more complex, have source control information mixed in, etc., which can all break or make a mess if we just copy from one place to another.  So I've written scripts to clean up this mess, and they do what we need for various different purposes (such as isolating a release build from source control and archiving it as a stand-alone solution)

Comment: Yes, perhaps writing a script can be an option, but even then it would take few more seconds to execute then just copy a folder. I want it to be as less time consuming as possible. I'm mostly using VS editor and debugger with code that is in a single file, and would like to have a template to start with that I can easily copy, and this template would be copied few thousand times. I will navigate many times through the directory structure of the project, so I want   it to be as simple as possible, but still use the power of VS debugger and editor. Hope it explains the intentions better.

Comment: Hi Leonid, sorry your comment doesn't explain *why* you would need to do this. Also, usually the time to execute a script is negligible compared to manually carrying out the actions. Usually the requirements are more like 'must not lose my code', 'must be able to get back version 1.2.3.4', and the time taken is not so important.

Comment: Ok, so the answer to the question is - there is no way to make a simple copy (as defined in the question) of the project very quickly using out-of-the-box tools. Obviously, a script can be written to copy the project.

Answer (score 3):

copy the entire folder in the /projects , such as C:\Users\Username\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Project\ProjectName  to another location, such as your desktop and open it there. This preserves the directory and file structure that the project file is looking for. I personally back my whole projects directory up frequently, and I've never had any issue copying older than current project folders around.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work with Visual Studio 2010 (used to work with previous versions). Getting error message as in the image in the question above. It looks like it needs a parent project folder in which the project was created.

Comment: look at the directory structure i listed, the folder i told you to copy IS the parent folder of the entire solution. btw, it DOES work.

Comment: Yes, it will work if that is a parent folder, but that's not ideal solution for me. I would not like to copy the parent folder, as it effectively creates an unnecessary folder every time. I would like to avoid the complexity of navigating through one more folder every time when I want to open one of the copied projects.

Comment: Well, you did that wrong when you created the project.  Next time uncheck the "Create directory for solution" option.  Only if you know what you're doing of course.

Comment: *Create directory for solution* was unchecked when the project was created, see the link in the question above. If this was checked it would result in 2 unnecessary pass-through folders. There is a **solution folder**, **folder where solution has to be created** notions, and a **project folder**. By unchecking the checkbox you get rid of **project folder** and project files are created in the solution directory, that still leaves the other 2 - I would like to have one for the reasons in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Although I understand OP wants single-step solution, in general, copying a VS2010 C++ project into another in a solution is three-step process.

1. Copy entire folder of the project to another one and properly rename the folder in windows explorer
2. Rename project file in the renamed folder
3. In the same solution of VS 2010, Add -> existing project -> open the renamed project file

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

the error says could not locate "c:\user\admin\dropbox\training@uva\volumes\train@uva\void_template\main.cpp"

and http://dl.dropbox.com/u/33457177/Screenshots/void_template_2011-12-04_22-15-51.png

shows you place the main.cpp in "c:\user\admin\dropbox\training@uva\void_template\"

the path is different

so check the .vcxproj file,find  or something,maybe the config is wrong